# jQuery Mobile select menu data-native-menu="false" selected item color

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change jQuery Mobile select menu active item color 
from `blue`(default) to `red`. For some reason I can not get my code to work.

Here is my code so far in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08e77sr9/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css like this:

```css
.ui-btn.ui-btn-active {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="colormenu" data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
  <option value="sel1">test1</option>
  <option value="sel2">test2</option>
  <option value="sel3">test3</option>
  <option value="sel4">test4</option>
</select>
```